can Restsharpsigned 105.2.3 nuget package upgrade to Resharp 111.4.0 without any major changes?
I have read that Resharp does not provide support for RestSharpSigned 105.2.3. I wanted to update it to RestSharp 111.4.0. But I dont want to do ant major changes.
any good link or support to read documentation as documentation provided by restsharp is not enough. It not seems to cover my Question.

RestSharp 105.2.3 was release in 2015 () and 111.4.0 was just last week (July 2024). That's 9 years and 6 major versions. The major version of a package like RestSharp is usually updated when breaking changes are introduced. I would be surprised if there weren't any major changes.

Digging deeper RestSharp(Signed) 105.x targets .NET Framework 3.5 whereas 111.x targets .NET Framework 4.7.1+, .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET 6+. What version of .NET Framework are you using for your application?

Looking at the docs might help https://restsharp.dev/migration
